# make dropdown box fit inside wrapper without relative position

Tags: javascript, html, css

so when I hover over my username div a dropdown box appears. but this box is not always as wide as the username div which is of variable width, so it looks strange. I can solve this by changing the position of the drop down box to `relative`. But then when the box appears, the whole page moves down. Is there a way to keep the position as `absolute` but still contain it within the wrapper? here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jwykcxzh/) to demonstrate. Thank you for reading.

```
<div id = "wrapper" style = "border:1px solid red;">
          <div id = "username">hover over me</div>
            <div id = "accBox">
              <ul>
                <li>sign&nbsp;out</li>
                <li>my&nbsp;profile</li>
                <li>new&nbsp;account</li>
              <ul>
            </div>
        </div>


   #username{
       color:grey;
       cursor:default;

    }

#accBox{
    border:1px solid grey;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#fff;
}

#accBox ul{
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
}

#accBox li{
    list-style:none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding:6px;
    overflow:hidden;
    font-size:13px;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-align:left;
}

#accBox li:hover{
              background-color: #DAD6D6;
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up you your closing is <ul> it should be </ul>.

Comment: @LarryLane - thanks for the heads up, I just went through and changed them all. I wonder how long that error went unnoticed?

Comment: No problem I am glad I could help it doesn't change the effects of what you are trying to accomplish but it might have caused some headaches in the future.

Comment: I'm sure there are some browsers which wouldn't stand for it. Chrome lets you get away with a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to set `position: relative` on the parent `div` so that it contains your `absolute` dropdown:

```
<div style = "border:1px solid red;position: relative;">
```

Next you can set `left: 0; right: 0` on the dropdown to make it take the width:

```
#accBox{
    border:1px solid grey;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#fff;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jwykcxzh/1/)

Answer (score 2):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/jwykcxzh/4/)

Just Add

```
left:8px;
right:8px;
```

This will make the unordered list items just as wide as the div container #accBox. A smaller value will increase its width and a larger value will decrease its width.

to `#accBox`

Comment: in theory this works but you're not containing the element within a parent. So if OP was to ever add margin or change the width, this menu would extend past it because it is being positioned to the document and not its parent: [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jwykcxzh/14/)

Comment: for that i think, the op can just add a container div that contains just the accBox and the menu,thus he can give the width as 100% @jmore009